# What fixture to use for Particles in Box2d?

Tags: box2d, game-physics

I am making a game using box2D and I need a particle system. I need the particles to eat up as less cpu as possible, while bouncing off other objects. I don't absolutely need the particles to interact with each other or to accumulate on objects. I will be using the particles for graphics and I am planing on simulating a lot of them.

Does anyone know the best kind of fixture to use for each particle? A point with no dimensions and without volume seems to be the best choice, but it seems that it doesn't exist in box2d. What other fixture shape would use the less cpu?

I am using Box2dWeb, a JavaScript port of box2d, but I don't think that matters much, as all Box2d ports are supposed to be similar, right?

Answer (score 4):

Google LiquidFun, recently released, supports particles and is an extension of box2d.

http://google.github.io/liquidfun/

Answer (score 3):

If you want fully-fledged bodies the best you can do is a small circle fixture.

Rolling your own point particle would not be too hard - I would probably try moving them with verlet integration, raycast from the previous position to the new position to check for collisions with the world, and use the collision normal to change the particle direction. If you don't need the particles to affect anything else in the world this would be a much lighter way to go. Fast-moving dynamic bodies might be able to go through some particles if the beginning and end of the particle's raycast were both already inside the body, but that may just look ok. At least the particles would not be able to go through static bodies.

If you used bodies with fixtures they could be made to ignore each other by setting their collision filter appropriately.